# The covariant derivative from the contravariant derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, covariance

I know that the following is true:
$$V^{\mu}_{~~~~~;\nu} = \frac{\partial V^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}} +\Gamma^{\mu}_{~\sigma\nu} V^{\sigma}.$$

Also, by definition, we have that $V_{\rho} = g_{\rho\nu}V^{\nu}$.

I would like to show that
$$V_{\rho;\nu} = \frac{\partial V_{\rho}}{\partial x^{\nu}} - \Gamma^{\sigma}_{~\rho\nu} V_{\sigma}$$

I have attempted to do this by taking $(g_{\rho\nu}V^{\nu})_{;\mu}$ and using the Leibniz rule and the fact that $g_{\rho\nu;\mu}=0$ but I am missing the minus sign!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\m{\mu}
\def\n{\nu}
\def\r{\rho}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\t{\tau}
\def\G{\Gamma}$While the method in @DanielC's answer is often the one followed it is possible, straightforward, and instructive to approach this in the way you have outlined in your question statement. 
We have 
\begin{align*}
V_{\r;\n} &= (g_{\r\m}V^\m)_{;\n} \\
&= \underbrace{g_{\r\m;\n}}_0 V^\m + g_{\r\m}V^\m_{;\n} \\
&= g_{\r\m}(V^\m_{,\n} + \G^\m_{\ \s\n}V^\s) \\ 
&= g_{\r\s}V^\s_{,\n} + \G_{\r\s\n}V^\s \\
&= (g_{\r\s}V^\s)_{,\n} - g_{\r\s,\n}V^\s + \G_{\r\s\n}V^\s \\
&= V_{\r,\n} - (g_{\r\s,\n} - \G_{\r\s\n})V^\s \\
&= \ldots \\
&= V_{\r,\n} - \G^\t_{\ \r\n}V_\t.  
\end{align*}
In the omitted steps one will need to use the well-known identity 
$$g_{\r\s,\n} = \G_{\s\r\n} + \G_{\r\n\s},$$
where 
$\G_{\r\s\t} = g_{\m\r} \G^\m_{\ \s\t}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to do it. You need to compute $$\nabla_\mu \left( V^\alpha V_\alpha\right) $$ using the Leibniz rule and the fact that there is a scalar inside the bracket.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer! So we can say that the covariant derivative you stated is equal to 0?

Comment: After using this method, I now have a '-' sign in front of $V_{\rho ,\nu}$. Could you expand your answer a bit please to help me see what I am missing?

Comment: The covariant derivative of a scalar is equal to the regular partial derivative of that scalar. So you need to apply the Leibniz rule again and subtract alike terms.

Comment: I have just noticed that, sorry for the confusion! I also need to use that permutation of indices for Christoffel symbols are antisymmetric, right?

Comment: Well, the indices of the Christoffel symbols are symmetric, if the metric is covariantly constant.